# Live streaming without sound via HDMI

Tags: hdmi, obs-studio

I'm live streaming via a camcorder via hdmi into a audio and video capture card into obs. I have a seperate sound source which also runs into the capture card and straight into obs. However I do not want the sound which comes in from the camera via hdmi. Is there anyway to stop it? Any help gratefully appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! What capture card are you using?

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aw/d/B08NX5D49Y/ref=sspa_mw_detail_6?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: Hmm, okay. I think the best thing might be to disable the audio out on your camera. What camera do you have?

Comment: I have already been in touch with JVC there is no way to disable the audio out of the camera - its only a basic camera which is annoying but I think we might have managed to find a solution - but thank you for your time!

Comment: No worries. You can also run the audio input directly into your computer rather than the capture card and set the audio offset manually; it's a little more annoying but it should work just fine.

Comment: Cool! I’ll go ahead and add it as an answer then so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you can’t disable the audio out on your camera or set the audio input on your capture card, you could just run the auxiliary audio input directly into your computer (rather than the capture card) and set the audio offset manually. It’s a little more annoying, but it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In OBS for my webcam which has a mic on it I can choose the mic as part of the audio input capture.  I then set that up and don't add it as a source to my scene which solves my problem.  I also mute the source as I will never need it as I have another mic for that purpose.